# Link questions in http://sitename.com/reputation

Tags: script

I find the `/reputation` page on all sites (for example: https://stackoverflow.com/reputation/) to be very helpful. Here is an example of what it looks like:

```
 2  17626610 (10)
 2  17626610 (10)
 2  17626610 (10)
-- 2013-07-13 rep +30   = 11374     
 2  14491966 (5)
-- 2013-07-14 rep +5    = 11379     
 2  17622882 (10)
-- 2013-07-15 rep +10   = 11389     
 2  16599613 (10)
-- 2013-07-17 rep +10   = 11399     
 2  17713345 (10)
 2  17713345 (10)
 2  17713345 (10)
 2  17713345 (10)
 2  17713345 (10)
 1  17713345 (15)
 1  17717574 (2)
 2  17581858 (10)
-- 2013-07-18 rep +77   = 11476     
 2  17736903 (10)
 2  17736903 (10)
 2  15648325 (10)
 2  15648325 (10)
 3  17738987 (-1)
 2  17740252 (10)
 2  17740252 (10)
 2  17740252 (10)
 2  17740252 (10)
 2  17740252 (10)
 1  17740252 (15)
 2  17740252 (10)
 2  17741226 (10)
 3  17741556 (-1)
 2  17741226 (10)
 3  17741539 (-1)
 2  17741226 (10)
 1  17741226 (15)
 2  17742171 (10)
 2  17742171 (10)
 1  17742171 (15)
 2  17740252 (10)
 2  17742171 (10)
-- 2013-07-19 rep +212  = 11688
```

(This is an excerpt from mine.) It shows all reputation changes, and it shows how much rep you gained per day. The only problem I have with it is that those numbers (the post ID) aren't clickable! So, I have made a userscript to rectify that. Here it is:

```
(p=document.body.children[0]).innerHTML=p.innerHTML.replace(/(\d+)(?= [\(\[])/g,'<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/q/$1/">$1</a>')
```

Yep, it's that simple. After running it, all of the IDs will be links!

[image: (image)]

Enjoy!

Comment: (and yes, I am aware that I have revealed some posts that I have downvoted; I don't mind.)

Comment: Should be `Linkify`, not `Link`. :P